# How to make python replace a specific answer to something?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make Python replace an answer if it is `"main()"`, but all I see when I run it is:

```
File "G:\PythonSoftware\Kaelan'sPythonExperiments\stuff.py", line 2
if name == "main()"
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

and it cuts back to CMD.

This is what I've got currently:

```
name = input("Enter a name for your Character: ")
 if name == "main()"
 name = Dave
age = input("What is your Character's Age?: ")
 if age == "main()"
 name = "15"
print("" + name + " is " + age + " years old.")
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Your indentation, it's wrong in nearly every line. Indentation is part of the Python syntax.

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive, your indentation is incorrect and you're missing colons after the if statements

Comment: Maybe try [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python-3) first?

Comment: There are many things wrong with the code, and also the *expected result* is strange. Why should the string `"main()"` have any special meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the defaults prior to **main** as follows:

```
name = 'Dave'
age = 15

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("Enter a name for your Character: ")
    age = input("What is your Character's Age?: ")
    print("" + name + " is " + age + " years old.")
```

...and below is a simple include example of the above (assuming it is called Hello.py):

```
from Hello import name, age

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(name, age)
```

If run from CMD prompt you will be asked for the input. If included then will use the defaults.

Comment: Enter a name for your Character: main()
What is your Character's Age?: main()
main() is main() years old.

Comment: the bottom one did: Dave 15
Enter a name for your Character: main()
What is your Character's Age?: main()
main() is main() years old.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. I found it out

```
name = input("Enter a name for your Character: ")
if name == 'main()':
 name = 'Dave'
age = input("What is your Character's Age?: ")
if age == 'main()':
 age = '15'
print("" + name + " is " + age + " years old.")
```